# Ember RSVP promise stopped working

Tags: ajax, ember.js, promise

For some reason an RSVP promise I created in an action stopped working for me and I can't figure out what when wrong where to make it stop working.

I have a component that sends an action and waits for a response

```
// COMPONENT IN ITEM ROUTE
callAjaxAction() {
  this.setProperties({working:true});
  Ember.RSVP.cast(this.attrs.action()).finally(() => {
    Ember.$('.draggable').animate({
      left: 0
    });
    this.setProperties({working:false});
  });
}
```

This particular instance of the component calls this action in the controller

```
// IN ITEM CONTROLLER
placeBid() {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    if(this.get('winning')) {
      this.get('notification')._confirm({message: "You are currently the highest bidder, would you like to continue with your bid?",isConfirm: true}).then(()=>{
        console.log('confirmed');
        this.send('placeBidActual').then(()=>{
          resolve();
        }).catch(()=>{
          reject();
        });
        return true;
      }).catch(()=>{
        resolve();
        console.log('denied');
        return false;
      });
    } else {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.send('placeBidActual').then(()=>{
          resolve();
        }).catch(()=>{
          reject();
        });
      },500);
    }
  });
}
```

This action is calling a confirm method on a service and waiting for the user to hit yes in the case of the user already winning this item. Otherwise I'm just calling the actual ajax action right away, that action looks like this

```
// IN ITEM CONTROLLER
placeBidActual() {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    Ember.$.ajax({
      ...
    }).then((response)=>{
      (do some stuff with the response)
      resolve();
    }, (reason)=>{
      (do something with rejection reason)
      reject(reason);
    });
  });
}
```

In the console I'm getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

On the line where it states `this.send('placeBidActual')`

**UPDATE:**

Here is maybe a better explanation to the expected process flow.

The user attempts to place a bid, the user swipes a component over to indicate they wish to bid. The UI at this point shows a loading indicator and waits for the ajax action to complete before it resets the UI. 
If the user is not already the highest bidder of the item it will go straight to the ajax action and upon completion signifies to the component to reset the UI. 
However, if the user is the highest bidder of the item it should instead show a confirm message (using the notification service I have setup) and wait for the user to either confirm or deny. If they deny it just cancels and signifies to the component to reset the UI. If the user confirms then it calls the ajax action and upon completion signifies to the component to reset the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer:
This isn't working because `send` doesn't return the value of the action.

I suggest moving the `placeBidActual` action to a method on the controller and call it like any normal method. This way you will get the return value and be able to call `.then` on it.

Comment: `callAjaxAction` is in the component because it needs to response to a complete ajax call to reset the UI. `placeBid` and `placeBidActual` are in the controller for `item` which is the active route. The service in this case is a `notification` service that has a confirm method. It should wait for the user to hit yes and then proceed with making the ajax call. Updated question with short process explanation.

Comment: ok but `placeBidActual` also an action then right? Do you need it to be an action? If you would call it directly as a method (instead of using `this.send..`) it will have a return value and work properly, did you try it this way?

Comment: Doesn't NEED to be an action, it was the only way I thought I should do it, I moved it into a method and called it like `this.PlaceBid()` and all works fine. If you want to update your answer to suggest a method I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

You should pass a function, whithout invoke it.

> Instead this:
> `Ember.RSVP.cast(this.attrs.action()).finally(() =>`
>
> Try it:
> `Ember.RSVP.cast(this.attrs.action).finally(() =>`

Invoking the funcion `this.attrs.action()` does it pass undefined for the Promise.

Comment: Doesn't fire the action at all doing it the way you suggest